# nhibernate VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate, configuration

I've found examples for configurate NHibernate in command line but in C# and I need it in vb, but I don't find how to do it.
So the question is how to write this in vb:

```
configuration.Proxy(proxy => proxy.ProxyFactoryFactory<ProxyFactoryFactory>());

configuration.DataBaseIntegration(db =>
{
    db.Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>();
    db.ConnectionString = Sql.db;
    db.BatchSize = 100;
    db.LogSqlInConsole = true;
});
```

Note: I don't want to do it in XML.

Comment: You should note that if your domain objects will require events, you can not use nhibernate with visual basic, because visual basic does not support virtual events. #foundthatoutthehardway

Comment: Why the downvote? Absolutely legitimate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeed!!!

I've 2 working sollutions:

```
Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
dictionary.Add("dialect", "NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect")
dictionary.Add("connection.provider", "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider")
dictionary.Add("connection.connection_string", Sql.db)
dictionary.Add("proxyfactory.factory_class", "NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle")
configuration.AddProperties(dictionary)
configuration.AddAssembly("Core")
```

and Meta-Knight one (with sub instead of function)

```
configuration.Proxy(Sub(proxy) proxy.ProxyFactoryFactory(Of ProxyFactoryFactory)())
configuration.DataBaseIntegration( _
                Sub(db)
                    db.Dialect(Of MsSql2008Dialect)()
                    db.ConnectionString = Sql.db
                    db.BatchSize = 100
                    db.LogSqlInConsole = True
                End Sub)
configuration.AddAssembly("Core")
```

Both Are working well but i did have an other problem with the XML files!

i did this in C# and it was working well:

```
 <class name="Core.Product, Core" table="Product">
    <class name="Product">
```

But in VB you HAVE TO add the project name in class definition like this :

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Core.Product, Core">
```

Hope this will help other people!

Thanks to every one

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
configuration.Proxy(Sub(proxy) proxy.ProxyFactoryFactory(Of ProxyFactoryFactory)())

configuration.DataBaseIntegration( _
    Sub(db)
        db.Dialect(Of MsSql2008Dialect)()
        db.ConnectionString = Sql.db
        db.BatchSize = 100
        db.LogSqlInConsole = True
    End Sub)
```

Comment: The first one should be `Function`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to find documentation for the Proxy and/or ProxyFactoryFactory methods, to no avail.

Comment: Likewise. But I’m confident given the usage: the function returns a factory (from a “factory factory”) that creates the proxy used by NHibernate, which is passed to the configuration via the `Proxy` method.

Comment: Yes it does make sense for it to be a Function :-)

Comment: i've already try that... 

`configuration.Proxy(Function(proxy) proxy.ProxyFactoryFactory(Of ProxyFactoryFactory)())` But i get an error "Expression does not produce a value."

If i do a sub in place of function.. it's working but it seems that i get a proxy problem.. because i do not get anny answer to any criteria